# How CES function becomes MINIMUM function?

Tags: limits, economics

> Let the CES  utility function be $$U(x,y)=\frac{x^\delta}{\delta}+\frac{y^\delta}{\delta},$$where $\delta\leq1,\delta\neq0.$ For $\delta=-\infty$, the given function is equivalent to $U(x,y)=\min(x,y)$.

How for $\delta=-\infty$ the function becomes $U(x,y)=\min(x,y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not this CES representation. Use this one (same preferences but different utilities): 
$$ U(x,y)=\left(x^\delta+y^\delta\right)^\frac{1}{\delta}$$  Now you can (and should) prove that: $$ \lim_{\delta\searrow-\infty}\dfrac{ U(x,y)}{\min(x,y)} = 1. $$

Assume $x=\min(x,y)\le y$ if the minimum is $y$ then just change the labels.

\begin{align*} \dfrac{ U(x,y)}{\min(x,y)} = \dfrac{\left(x^\delta+y^\delta\right)^\frac{1}{\delta}}{\min(x,y)}=\left( \dfrac{x^\delta+y^\delta}{\min(x,y)^\delta}\right)^\frac{1}{\delta}=\left( \dfrac{x^\delta+y^\delta}{\min(x,y)^\delta}\right)^\frac{1}{\delta}=\\
\left( \dfrac{x^\delta}{\min(x,y)^\delta}+\dfrac{y^\delta}{\min(x,y)^\delta}\right)^\frac{1}{\delta}=\left( \left(\dfrac{x}{\min(x,y)}\right)^\delta+\left(\dfrac{y}{\min(x,y)}\right)^\delta\right)^\frac{1}{\delta}=\left(1+\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)^\delta\right)^\frac{1}{\delta}
\end{align*}
Notice that the limit as $\delta$ goes to minus infinity of the term inside the parenthesis is $1$ if $x<y$ and $2$ if $y=x$ regardless the exponent outside the parenthesis, $\frac{1}{\delta}$ converges to zero as $\delta\rightarrow-\infty$ so you have a positive term being raised to the power of zero in the limit, which is 1 as we wanted to show.

Comment: What is $\searrow$ here?

Comment: It is the same as $\rightarrow$, we are taking the limit as $\delta$ goes down to minus infinity. Because you can't just plug $\delta=-\infty$ into the expression for $U$.

Comment: Sir, I really can't handle $\min$ function, please elaborate the answer! I will be obliged.

Comment: At chatroom, I got the answer by [pedro](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/23350/pedro-tamaroff) : "Suppose $0<x<y$. Then $r=y/x>1$, so $r^\delta\to 0$ as $\delta \to-\infty$.
But $${\left( {{x^\delta } + {y^\delta }} \right)^{\frac{1}{\delta }}} = x{\left( {1 + {{\left( {\frac{y}{x}} \right)}^\delta }} \right)^{\frac{1}{\delta }}}$$"

Comment: Thank you so much sir for correcting my CES function, actually I learned from Nicholson-Snyder's Microeconomic Theory that the CES function is $U(x,y)=\frac{x^\delta}{\delta}+\frac{y^\delta}{\delta},$ and used it! How are yours and mine have same preferences?

Comment: All these functions are CES: the one you wrote, mine, etc... In economics we care only about preferences and not utilities. If $f$ is an increasing function, it does not matter if you use $U$ or $f(U)$. For example, you can represent the Cobb-Douglas preferences with $x^\alpha y ^\beta$ or with $\alpha\ln(x)+\beta\ln(y)$...

Comment: Let $f(U)=\left( \delta\cdot  U\right)^\frac{1}{\delta}$ for $\delta<0$ and $U<0$ this is a monotonic function as its derivative is always positive $f^\prime>0$. "Mine" CES is $f(U)$ and "yours" is $U$.

Comment: Sir, shouldn't it be $\delta>0$ AND $U>0$ ?

Comment: Aren't you taking delta to minus infinity? How it can be positive?

Comment: Sorry, I did it wrong. Let me ask it on yours:Let $f(U)=\left( \delta\cdot  U\right)^\frac{1}{\delta}$ for $\delta<0$ and $U<0$ then $f^\prime(U)>0$. How is that possible? My try is  $\frac{df}{dU}=U^{\frac1{\delta}-1}$, which is negative for $U<0$.

Comment: The derivative is wrong, the correct is $\frac{df}{dU}=\left(\delta U\right)^{\frac1{\delta}-1}>0$ if $\delta U>0$ so if $\delta<0$ then $U<0$.